# AStar with destructible obstacles

Tags: javascript, node.js, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I'm trying to implement AI behavior similar to Bomberman-like game.
I have 3 types of tiles, walkable, unwalkable(walls), and destructible(boxes, etc) which can become walkable if destroyed.
So, for example:

1. select random player-target
2. if there is a path, go
3. if there is no clear path, but it can be made by destroying something, go to destructible tile, and destroy it
4. if there is no path, change target

Any ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat your graph as a [weighted graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Weighted_graphs_and_networks).  Give each walkable tile `weight=1` and each destructible tile a much larger weight *(`weight = total number of tiles` would work - it just needs to be larger than the longest possible path)*.

This will cause the AI to destroy the least number of tiles necessary to reach the target.